# Gif loader while loading heavy png image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load png image generated by server-side PHP script (chart) to the HTML IMG-element `<img id="chart">` using following JS code:

`$('#chart').attr('src', 'chart.php');`

The PNG-image generation and downloading takes about 1 second, so I want to show gif loader while image is loading. How to implement this feature with JS?

Comment: BTW, the code you show is jquery syntax and not javascript, but you do not have a jquery tag in  your question. So do you want a javascript or jquery answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#chart').attr('src', 'chart.php').load(function(){
    //something
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I  have implemented it this way: `$('#ajax-loader').attr('src', 'ajax-loader.gif');
$('#chart').hide();
$('#chart').attr('src', linkUrl).load(function(){
$('#ajax-loader').hide(); $('#chart').show();});`

Answer (score 2):

For balance this is very simple to do in plain JS:

```
var preload = function(element, src) {

   var img = new Image();

   // Apply onload before applying src attribute to avoid IE prematurely firing
   img.onload = function() {
       // Replace #chart with image
       element.parentNode.replaceChild(img, element);
   };

   img.src = src;
}

preload(document.getElementById('chart'), 'chart.php?_...');
```

Comment: Nice to see someone using pure javascript, as a note you would probably be better using the more modern "addEventListener" in favour of "onload".

Comment: @Xotic750 Why is it nice that would you want to use vanilla Javascript for something like this? The `onload` isn't even implemented correctly in this answer anyways..

Comment: Not every one can or wants to include jquery or other libraries when they are writing code. And yes he has a problem with his "onload" usage.

Comment: Fixed onload declaration - hasty typing. `onload` will work everywhere being DOM level 1, `addEventListener` will not (thinking mainly of legacy IE here) and in this instance it's more typing with no benefits that I can think of other than feeling more modern.

Comment: That is true, the newer method advantages where supported, it is much faster is one. http://jsperf.com/addeventlistener-vs-onload

Comment: If you want to see the one that I prepared before they changed the tag to jquery, it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/GYE3d/

Answer (score 1):

In case the browser caches it, you may way to add something to the query string to break that. Either way, you need to listen for the image's `load` event, which should be bound *before* setting its `src` (in case it's cached):

```
var target_url = 'chart.php?_=' + (new Date()).getTime();
// Show "loading"
$('#chart').on("load", function () {
    // Hide "loading"
}).attr('src', target_url);
```

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Note the caveats near the bottom of that reference, referring to the event when working with images:

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
- Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache